# Issue with sending a .csv file through ajax to PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

I was wondering how I could go about sending a .csv file from a file input container in HTML to another .php file in ajax.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $(".Rsubmit").click(function () {

          ?????What would I declare to contain the .csv file?
          var checkurl = './CSVRemove/getAccountsCSV.php';
          runCSVcheck(checkurl);

        });
    });

    function runCSVcheck(checkurl)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        url: checkurl,
        data:
        {
            ???? what would I put here?
        },
        success: function(response) {
            code....
        });


    }
```

HTML:

```
Input boxes.....

<span>Enter .csv File: </span><input type="file" name="file" value="" />
```

Please let me know if there is a solution!

David

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on sending a file upload via Ajax, I suggest using a jQuery form plugin that support file uploads.

There are a number of them available, but I've had good success with this one: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

It allows you to post a form via Ajax, even if the form includes file upload fields. PHP will receive the form post exactly as it would have done normally if it had been posted via a regular form submit.

Alternatively, you could use HTML5's file API, but only if you don't need to support older browsers like IE8. The jQuery form plugin is probably the safer way to go for now.

hope that helps.